# DateTimeAxis - set Label to display Date + Time

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Is there a way in flex 3 chart component to display both the date and time using horizontal DateTimeAxis?

Currently the DateTimeAxis element has an attribute dataunits which allows to set the value to any of "milliseconds|seconds|minutes|hours|days|weeks|months|years" but I want to display the label as "2009/09/15 06:00:00" which includes the day and the time too.

Here is the sample that i'm using

```
[Bindable]
 public var deck:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {date:"2009-09-15 06:00:00", close:42.71},
    {date:"2009-09-16 06:15:00", close:42.99}

 ]);

 public function myParseFunction(s:String):Date {
   var sDate = s.substring(0,s.indexOf(" "));
   var sTime = s.substring(s.indexOf(" "));
   var aDate = sDate.split("-");
   var aTime = sTime.split(":");
   return new Date(aDate[0],(aDate[1]*1-1),aDate[2],aTime[0],aTime[1],aTime[2],0);
 }
```

]]>

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you have to extend the <mx:DateTimeAxis> (unfortunately).

However, it is not hard to do, and an example is posted here: http://codeznips.blogspot.com/2010/12/escape-american-date-format-in.html

You'd might have to extend the example above further by adding a `formatSeconds()` and set `formatStringSeconds = "YYYY/MM/DD JJ:NN:SS"`.

Or possibly just use the existing `formatStringDays` and set `dataUnits = "days"`, like this:

```
<mx:horizontalAxis>
    <charts:FormattedDateTimeAxis
         formatStringDays="YYYY/MM/DD JJ:NN:SS"
         dataUnits = "days"/> 
</mx:horizontalAxis>
```

Vegard